# Fetch error message triggered by each rejected e-mail address

Tags: php, swiftmailer

The `Swift_Mailer::send()` method adds failed address to its second parameter:

```
$numSent += $mailer->send($message, $failedRecipients);
```

Is there a simple way to fetch the exact error message triggered by each rejected e-mail address?

So far, I've enabled the `Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger` logger and I'm able to `dump()` it but the resulting array contains the full SMTP conversation and I'm forced into some nice string parsing:

```
++ Starting Swift_SmtpTransport
<< 220 smtp.example.com ESMTP Postfix
>> EHLO [127.0.0.1]
<< 250-smtp.example.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10485760
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
[...]
>> RCPT TO: <info@example.con>
<< 450 4.1.2 <info@example.con>: Recipient address rejected: Domain not found
!! Expected response code 250/251/252 but got code "450", with message "450 4.1.2 <info@example.con>: Recipient address rejected: Domain not found"
>> RSET
<< 250 2.0.0 Ok
```

While it isn't a big deal, I wonder if I'm missing a better alternative.